# How to render a WPF UserControl to a bitmap without creating a window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, graphics

How can I render a WPF UserControl to a bitmap without creating a window? I need to render a WPF UserControl and upload it to another program. The bitmaps will be rendered through a Windows Service, so creating a window is not an option (I know there's ways to 'virtually' create windows, but unfortunately anything that calls a command to create a window is NOT an option in my case). Is there a way to RENDER the UserControl without binding it to a Window?

Comment: Perhaps you could supply a little more information.  If the User Control can't be rendered, why does it even exist?  It is a visual element.

Comment: It needs to be rendered, but not directly to a display (so there can be no window). It's being rendered to an OpenGL cube. The cube rendering works, but currently I have to create a separate window to do the rendering in. It would be nice if I didn't need a separate window for the WPF rendering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ended up using an HwndHost with no actual window.

```
void cwind()
    {
        Application myapp = new Application();
        mrenderer = new WPFRenderer();
        mrenderer.Width = 256;
        mrenderer.Height = 256;

        HwndSourceParameters myparms = new HwndSourceParameters();
        HwndSource msrc = new HwndSource(myparms);
        myparms.HwndSourceHook = new HwndSourceHook(ApplicationMessageFilter);

        msrc.RootVisual = mrenderer;
        myapp.Run();
    }
    static IntPtr ApplicationMessageFilter(
IntPtr hwnd, int message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Comment: I had to modify your solution a bit to make it work for me, but using a Win32 wrapper to force WPF to load in a hidden window is a great idea.

Comment: @floele: maybe for some solutions, a `Win32` wrapper is a great idea. But in this case, I think @RQDQ has the proper solution.

Comment: Please tell me What is WPFRenderer? (where is that assembly file and namespace)

Comment: Two comments:

1) WPFRenderer appears to be a custom UserControl.

2) This solution is the best because it supports Bindings. Simply creating, measuring, and arranging a UserControl (as @RQDQ) has suggested is a simpler, more elegant solution but does not support Bindings. So I guess it depends on your use case what you should do.

Comment: This is also the solution if you want to render animations \ storyboards in your xaml.

Answer (score 71):

Have you tried spinning up an instance of the user control and doing something like this:

```
UserControl control = new UserControl1();

control.Measure(new Size(300, 300));
control.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(300,300)));

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(300, 300, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

bmp.Render(control);

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"c:\test.png"))
   encoder.Save(stm);
```

It looks like you need to Measure, Arrange.  This worked for me.

Comment: Google search to export a user control to a JPG brought me here and this answer was perfect. Thanks very much.

Comment: This works really well however underlying styles are not properly applied to the user control. I'm not sure how to overcome that at the moment, otherwise a perfect solution!

Comment: To make this work, did you have to have the control previously displayed?  I am creating a window and will get black output unless I previously Show() and Close() the window.

Comment: If it helps someone, calling `control.UpdateLayout()` immediately after `Arrange()` did the trick for me.

Comment: @SteveRobbins Interestingly enough, I got the same result you did when calling this from my main method on the control itself.  But when I moved the code into the Control and just called the method on the specific element (i.e. specific Control within my control that I wanted) it behaved as described.  This is in addition to having to call control.UpdateLayout() per (at)dotNET's suggestion so that it had my data from my DataContext instead of just a blank grid.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, if you call `control.UpdateLayout()` after measuring and arranging, the user control doesn't need to be in any window.

Answer (score 1):

Based on IDWMaster's solution I did it a bit differently using the `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`. Otherwise the bindings were not up-to-date when the export to bitmap happened. This works for me (`this` is the WPF control to render):

```
System.Windows.Forms.UserControl controlContainer = new System.Windows.Forms.UserControl();
controlContainer.Width = width;
controlContainer.Height = height;
controlContainer.Load += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            bmp.Render(this);
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
            encoder.Save(fs);
            controlContainer.Dispose();
        }
    }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
};

controlContainer.Controls.Add(new ElementHost() { Child = this, Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill });
IntPtr handle = controlContainer.Handle;
```